# How to change the editor of an app in the appstore?

Tags: iphone

My company had an app developp by a freelance, we didnt have an Appstore dev account at the moment so he published the app with his name. Now we have recruited an iphone app on our team, and open a dev account. 
How can I transfer the app without loosing the users who already installed the app  ? (I mean how can I avoid the have a duplicate of the app on the appstore without loosing previous user if I do an update).

Is it a least possible ?

Thank you .

Comment: Contact Apple, but I suspect it's not possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No it's not. Sorry.